# Partitioned exists clause in condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following query:

```
select user_id,
case when event='Analysis' 
and max(case when event='Strat' then max_time end) over(partition by user_id) >
max(case when event='Analysis' then max_time end) over(partition by user_id) then null 
**when event like 'Premium:%' and exists max(select distinct event from sub where event='Complete') over(partition by user_id) then null**
else event end event
from (
select distinct user_id, event, 
[*bunch of other columns*]
max(time) max_time
from table
[*bunch of joins and filters*]
group by 1,2
) sub
```

In the row with ** I am trying to add a clause such that: if `event like 'Premium:%'` but user has an `event='Complete'` (at any point) then change to `event is null`.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a conditional sum in window function, partitioning by user id:

```
case 
    when event like 'Premium:%' 
    and sum(case when event='Complete' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id)>0 
    then null 
else event end
```